# getting row number of spesific record after ordering with mysql

Tags: mysql

i have simple mysql table which contains only email and point fields.
I want to order by point then find row number of given email address.
How can i do it? Thank you.

I tried something like this but get error:

```
    SELECT email, point,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY point) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM `simpletable`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT email, point, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
FROM `simpletable`
CROSS JOIN (select @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY point
```

Comment: if i want to get spesific row with rank of all table, what must i do? thanks.

Comment: Use `LIMIT` with offset. See the MySQL doc for it.

Comment: Thanks. I mean get row position of spesific record after ordering according to point?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly. If you can't find a solution or similar question here, then post a new one and explain in detail what you have, what you need and what problems you have getting there.